# Copy hyperlinks from original list to search index list

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I've created a search index (using formulas) from a list of products that have hyperlinks attached (created with Insert Hyperlink). The search index is created without the hyperlinks however.

Both lists are on the same worksheet.

I would like a macro that ensures the hyperlinks are carried across when the search index is created. I would also like it so that when a search is carried out, the correct hyperlinks stay with the product (at the moment, if I manually put the hyperlinks into the search index, when I use search the hyperlinks stay in the cell, not with the product they relate to).

Also, I saw on another thread here a bit in a macro that stops the font auto-formatting in the hyperlink style. It would be good if this could be incorporated.

This is the macro I've tried:

```
Sub CopyHyperlinks()
Dim Source As Range
Dim Destination As Range
Dim SearchRange As Range
Set SearchRange=Sheets(1).Range("E4:E68")
Set Source=SearchRange(1,1)
Set Destination=Sheets(1).Range("B4")
For Each Source In SearchRange
    If Source.Hyperlinks.Count>0 Then
        Destination.Hyperlinks.Add Destination
        Source.Hyperlinks(1).Address,,,Source.Text
    End If
    Set Destination=Destination(2,1)
Next Source
End Sub
```

I found this macro after doing a search on the internet and have tried to change it to suit what I need. When I use it, it appears to copy the hyperlink (the font autoformatting appears on the text) but the hyperlink hasn't copied across fully)

Comment: Can you post a link to the macro you saw which stopped the autoformatting?